# Tkinter: How can I determine the position of a Toplevel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

The title says it all really, I have a piece of code in which I would like to move the top-level in relation to its old position.

To do this I need to fetch the current position of the window, then set the new position using `root.geometry('+x+y')`.  How can I find the current position of a TopLevel?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can get the window's position through the [`winfo_x`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.winfo_x-method) and [`winfo_y`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.winfo_y-method) methods.

Below is a simple script to demonstrate*:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button
root = Tk()
def click():
    print(root.winfo_x(), root.winfo_y())
Button(text="Get position", command=click).grid()
root.mainloop()
```

---

*Note: I used a `Tk` window here instead of a `Toplevel` for the sake of simplicity.  However, the same principle applies to the `Toplevel`.